Test works with --headless but fails without it
The following code navigates to an HTTP site.
There is something weird that happens when I run it via VS code.
When I'm looking at the network tab there are two requests, The first one, it tries to access the site via HTTP and gets 404 Not Found, and the second one tries to access via HTTP and gets 404 Temporary Redirect, and the site cannot be accessed.
I also tried to set "acceptInsecureCerts: true", but it didn't help.
When I'm running it using --headless the test works without any issues.
async getIframeUrl(lang) {
    let url = [Urls.iFrameURL, this.entity.entityName, this.entity.entitySuffix, "&idap=", this.entity.idap, "&cskin=brand"].join('');
    console.log(url);
    let urlLang = [Urls.iFrameURL, this.entity.entityName, this.entity.entitySuffix, "&idap=", this.entity.idap, "&cskin=brand", "&uiculture=", lang].join('');
    await browser.url(lang ? urlLang : url);
    await browser.refresh();
    await browser.switchToFrame(await $("#iframeId"));
    await (po.firstTab).waitForDisplayed({ timeout: 60000 * 5 })
}

Your help is appreciated.
